# the probability function of a random vector

Tags: probability-distributions, summation

We've got a random vector with the following probability funtion:
P(X=i,Y=j)=k(i+j) where (i,j) into the image of (X,Y) which is {(l,m) / 1<=l<=n and 1<=m<=q}
How can I calculate the value of k?

---

I know that to calculate k I have to calculate the summatory of the values of x and  y of k(i+j). But in this case I don't know how to do it because I don't know how many terms I have to sum. Is right that x goes from 1 to n and m goes from 1 to q? Anyway, I don't know how to do it in this case...

Comment: sum over the elements of the image

Comment: I don't understand what you say. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sum_{l=1}^{n}\sum_{m=1}^qP(X=l,Y=m)=1$$

Comment: Thanks! I've done this and what I've obatined is:  k = 2 / ( q*(n^2 + n + q +1) ). Would you be able to say to me if that's ok, please?

Comment: It is not okay. If $n$ and $q$ are interchanged then the outcome should stay the same (which is not okay). If I am not mistaking then your denominator should be $qn(n+q+2) $.